# Kronecker product and matrix multiplication property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

Given two symmetric matrices, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, is there any property of the Kronecker product which relates to matrix multiplication?

More specifically, what is $(A \otimes B)C$?  And what should the dimensions of $C$ be?

Comment: $C$ must have dimension $nm\times r$ for some $r>0$. The way I like to think of tensor products of matrices is matrices of matrices (with some sort of multiplication at each element) which suggests that we will have an $n\times n$ matrix of $m\times m$ matrices so $A\otimes B$ has dimensions $nm\times nm$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the product $(A \otimes B) C$, is there any theorem related to it?

Answer (score 10):

In general there is no nice formula for $(A\otimes B)C$. However, if you know $C=U\otimes V$, then
$$
(A\otimes B)(U\otimes V) = (AU)\otimes (BV).
$$
See[Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations).